# The value of an array changes without any command affecting it

Tags: java, arrays, variables

I am facing a weird problem in the following piece of code:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String args[]){
    int[] c = {0};
    int[] a = c;
    int[] b = c;

    a[0] = 1;
    b[0] = 2*a[0];

    System.out.println(" a " + a[0]);
}
}
```

This returns "a 2", and not "a 1", which means that the value of the array a changed, even though the operation is only supposed to affect the array b!
Does anyone know where this might come from, and how to solve it please?

Comment: I'm not sure how java implements arrays. But My assumption is that `a = c` and `b = c` causes `a` and `b` to refer to the same array that `c` refers to (i.e. `a[0]` and `b[0]` are actually the same memory position).

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4):

The culprit is here:

```
int[] c = {0};
int[] a = c;
int[] b = c;
```

You think you're creating three different arrays but really they're all pointing to the same array `c`.

```
System.out.println(a + "-" + b + "-" + c); //[I@1b6d3586-[I@1b6d3586-[I@1b6d3586
```

All variables are actually pointing at the same array in memory.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I got it !
- Would this still be a problem with all the other variable types? (int, double, etc.)?
- How can you create several distinct variables which are initialized with the same value? For instance, if I want to create 10 arrays initialized to the value {0}, do I have to do it one by one?

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is effectively create 2 copies of the same array as when you declare an array:

```
    int[] a = c;
```

This is the same as writing:

```
    int* a = c;
```

Writing, c is the same as &c[0], its the base address of the array.

So:

```
    int[] c = {0};
    int[] a = c;
    int[] b = c;

    a[0] = 1;  // This also sets the value of c[0] and b[0] to 1
    b[0] = 2*a[0]; // This is 2 * 1 = 2
```